# syntax error, unexpected '>' (View: /views/user/forms/project/projects.blade.php)

Tags: laravel

```
 function showProjects()
    {
    $.post("<?php echo e(route('show.front.profile.projects', $user->id)); ?> ) ", {user_id: <?php echo e($user - > id); ?>, _method: 'POST', _token: '<?php echo e(csrf_token()); ?>'})
            .done(function (response) {
            $('#projects_div').html(response);
            });
    }
```

Comment: Please go through https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking question. There is lack of introduction to your problem or information what you tried.

Comment: You need to provide more background of the problem - is the function a PHP function? or is it javascript function inside blade? Just briefly looking at the code, it looks like problem with `echo e($user - > id);` which is wrongly having spaces. Also check https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade#php for other options how to have code in blade.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP parse/syntax errors; and how to solve them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Comment: (I'd bet it's the `- >` bit...)

Answer (score 0):

Check the related view, I'm assuming the spaces in this `$user - > id` should be removed to become `$user->id`.